# unable to install mongodb due to unmet dependencies 20.04

Tags: apt, dependencies

I am trying to run `sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org` to install a mongodb server on my copy of ubuntu 20.04. I am receivcing this when I run the commmand

```
    Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mongodb-org : Depends: mongodb-org-shell but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-server but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-mongos but it is not going to be installed
               Depends: mongodb-org-tools but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

How do I fix this

Comment: How would I go about removing the other version and verifying that the previous version was removed?

Comment: Oh, wait, THIS is the non-Ubuntu version. What's wrong with the version in the Ubuntu repos?